# Visual Studio Code - Code Snippet cw Unexpected Behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

When using code snippets in Visual Studio Code, the behavior of `cw` which turns into `Console.WriteLine()` always includes the fully qualified name when it is auto completed, as follows.

```
System.Console.WriteLine()
```

However, I already have `using System;` declared at the top of my file.
Why does `VSCODE` insist on including the namespace in the code snippet?
I am expecting it to auto complete into this,

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

Is this normal behavior to be expected from `VSCODE`?

Comment: Did you include `<Imports><Import><Namespace>System</Namespace></Import></Imports>` under the snippet element?

Comment: @C.Helling I have made no modifications to the default install of VSCODE. I am not an experienced programmer, still learning C#, and I am currently looking further into snippet elements to see whats going on.

Comment: I think this feature is only supported for vb, not c#. Is it really a problem to use the fully-qualified name?

Comment: @C.Helling No, it is not a big problem at the end of the day. But we declare using namespaces for a reason, right? To make our code concise and readable? I figured the intellisense would be smart enough to know that I had declared using System and thus remove the namespace from the code snippet, just like in Visual Studio IDE. How do I access the code snippet elements to have a look at whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible and tracked in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10561

Answer (score 0):

**maybe you can create a snippet in VSC**:

1. ctrl+shift+p
2. Configure user snippets
3. Csharp

```
{   "Print ConsoleWriteLine()": {
        "prefix": "cw",
        "body": [
            "Console.WriteLine($0);"
        ],
        "description": "Print line of code"
    }
}
```